# React Material UI hide table column and show onAdd

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of table columns where I want to hide password column and show only when `onAdd` functionality is triggered.

```
columns: [
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Email', field: 'email' },
        { title: 'Phone', field: 'phone' },
        { title: 'Location', field: 'location' },
        { title: 'Username', field: 'username' },
      //{ title: 'Password', field: 'password', editable: 'onAdd' },
    ],
```

MaterialTable

```
 <MaterialTable
            columns={state.columns}
            data={state.data}
            editable={{
                onRowAdd: (newData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve();
                            setState((prevState) => {
                                const data = [...prevState.data];
                                data.push(newData);
                                return { ...prevState, data };
                            });
                        }, 600);
                    })
            }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-with-hidden-columns-cndj4?file=/src/Components/TestList.jsx):

The solution is to add `hidden: true` to the object.

```json
{ title: "Seven", field: "seven", hidden: true }
```

Comment: can i get this hide columns data in rowdata object after hiding this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the column, but you can hide the value by overriding the render and editComponent props.

```
columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Email', field: 'email' },
    { title: 'Phone', field: 'phone' },
    { title: 'Location', field: 'location' },
    { title: 'Username', field: 'username' },
    { title: 'Password', field: 'password', render: () => null,
       editComponent: props => (
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.value}
          onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      ) },
],
```

This will hide the value: [image]

You could also show a password placeholder (***) as the password, you can do it like this:

```
render: rowData => <p>{rowData.password.split("").map(() => '*')}</p>
```

or just

```
render: rowData => <p>******</p>
```

To hide the length

Comment: could we hide the table column title as well?

Comment: You could override the Cell with https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding and hide the name if the rowData.tableData is editing.